# Combining data from two tables in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, formula, array-formulas

So, I have two tables. The first one has a column with four digit numbers (1009 total). The second one has a column with five digit numbers (7105 total). These 7105 numbers contain some of the 1009 ones from the first table, but with a different last digit. Let's say in the first table we have the number 1005 and in the second one there are 10057, 10058 and 10059. What I want to do is to get all the numbers from the big table that are matching the first four digits with those from the first table and insert them in there. I've tried with the VLOOKUP function, but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Please, help :)

Comment: Are you looking to use formulas or a macro? If there are 3 matching numbers, do you want these numbers all in one cell, or in 3 different columns? Is this something you need to do once, or something you need to do quite often? Does it matter if it takes several minutes to calculate, or does it need to be fast?

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to use. If there were 3 matching numbers, I want them in separate cells. And I think I'll have to do this quite often from now on.

Comment: Basically, you can write a macro to do this (which will be quick, but will require far more specific explanations from you to make work, both about how your data is structured, and what you want the results to look like), or you can write formulas (which will be slow, but are easy for you to adapt yourself to match your situation). As-is, the question is almost impossible to answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `VLOOKUP` on the second column with a modified lookup value:

Assuming that the big table is in Sheet2, the small one in Sheet1, there are no headers and the digits are both in column A of their respective sheet, put this in Sheet2, cell B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1, 4)*1, Sheet1!A:A, 1, 0)
```

And drag the formula down till the end of the table.

All those that have `#N/A` means there is no match in the smaller table. Otherwise, the matched digit will be returned.

EDIT: To explain my edit, `LEFT(A1, 4)` returns a text value, to convert the digit back to a number, multiply by 1.

Comment: It returned #N/A on every cell

Comment: @user2699272 Oops, my bad, I missed out 1 thing: `*1`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user2699272 Any luck?